# Determining the hour in daylight saving time

Tags: java, date

Probably, this question is asked many times but I might not find the correct keywords to find them.

There was a time change at 30.10. The time was set back to 2 o'clock at 03:00 o'clock (Europe/Berlin). That means, at that day, there were two 02:00 o'clock (before and after time change)

Currently, I have two date (java.util.Date) objects. One of them was created at the first 02:00 o'clock (before the time was set back) and the second one was created at the second 02:00 o'clock.

Is there any way to differentiate these objects based on whether it was created at the first or second 02:00 o'clock?

Comment: You should always record data in UTC with a timezone and offset

Comment: @EngineerDollery In my date object, there is a time zone info. Should I use it to differentiate the objects?

Comment: you should have a timezone offset in your date object

Comment: @Vimsha Yes, I have but the values in the timezone offset are same.

Comment: "I have two date objects": are you talking about `java.util.Date` or something else? A `java.util.Date` just holds the milliseconds since 1.1.1970 UTC, there is no time zone information contained. Thus the two dates would be one our apart.

Comment: you might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices

Comment: @Henry When I debung, under the date object, I see Gregorian date and in Gregorian date, there is a zoneInfo object.

Comment: Please tell us the fully qualified class name of the "date object".

Comment: @Henry As you said, it is java.util.Date

Comment: @Ad Infinitum - Please write code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Count from epoch

Your `java.util.Date` objects actually *are* in UTC but their `toString` method confusingly applies a time zone when generating the string output.

You can differentiate two `Date` objects by interrogating for their count from [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)). Internally the date-time is tracked as a number of milliseconds since first moment of 1970 in UTC. Call the badly-named method  [`java.util.Date::getTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--) to get a `long`.

## UTC

Record moments in [UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Every programmer should learn to think in UTC, work in UTC, do logging in UTC, and keep a second clock on their desk and screen set to UTC.

UTC is the *One True Time*. All others are mere variations, every time zone being a deviation from UTC.

Let me repeat the acronym one more time to be clear: **UTC**

## `Instant`

The [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class is your new best friend in this arena, your go-to class for date-time work. It represents a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

You need not worry about Daylight Saving Time (DST) cut-overs, politicians redefining DST ( often with little notice), nor other anomalies particular to any one time zone. Just use UTC.

To generate a String representing this moment, call `toString` for a string in standard ISO 8601 format. This string is always in UTC, so you don't have the problem of `Date::toString` applying a time zone while generating the string. The standard format has a `Z` on the end, short for `Zulu`, and means UTC.

> instant.toString():
>  2016-01-23T12:34:56.123456789Z

## Converting `Date`

Convert your `java.util.Date` objects to `Instant`. New conversion methods have been added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myUtilDate.toInstant();
```

## Zoned

I do not care about Berlin time. You, as a programmer, do not care about Berlin time. Your network and server admins do not care about Berlin time. We care about UTC.

The only people who care about Berlin time are end-users. For them, you can assign a time zone for presentation of data.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

Call `toString` to generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format but wisely extended by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

> 2016-07-07T08:00:15.768+02:00[Europe/Berlin]

Use `DateTimeFormatter` class to generate Strings representing the date-time value in other formats.

## DST in effect?

You can interrogate to determine if Daylight Saving Time (DST) is in effect for any particular `ZonedDateTime`.  See [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40431053/642706).

```
ZoneRules rules = zdt.getZone().getRules();
Boolean dstInEffect = rules.isDaylightSavings( zdt.toInstant() );
```